# Highlighting entire c/cpp macro definition in emacs?

Tags: c, emacs, macros, syntax-highlighting, multiline

In vim, entire c macro definition is fully highlighted with different color. How do i get similar style in emacs?.  You can refer below screenshot showing that in vim(right side), entire EXAMPLE_MACRO is highlighted and showing that CALL_MACRO(0) is part of the definition.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CALL_MACRO(x)                           \
    EXAMPLE_MACRO(x)                            \


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#define EXAMPLE_MACRO(x)                           \
    if (x) {                                       \
    printf("\n Condition is true");            \
} else {                                       \
    printf("\n Condition is false");           \
}                                              \
                                               \
CALL_MACRO(0);

CALL_MACRO(1);
#undef EXAMPLE_MARCO
}
```

major-mode for above code is c-mode.

Please note above code doesn't compile.

---

I found below code which can make #if 0 and #endif to be shown as font-lock.

```
(defun my-c-mode-font-lock-if0 (limit)
(save-restriction
(widen)
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((depth 0) str start start-depth)
    (while (re-search-forward "^\\s-*#\\s-*\\(if\\|else\\|endif\\)" limit 'move)
      (setq str (match-string 1))
      (if (string= str "if")
          (progn
            (setq depth (1+ depth))
            (when (and (null start) (looking-at "\\s-+0"))
              (setq start (match-end 0)
                    start-depth depth)))
        (when (and start (= depth start-depth))
          (c-put-font-lock-face start (match-beginning 0) 'font-lock-comment-face)
          (setq start nil))
        (when (string= str "endif")
          (setq depth (1- depth)))))
    (when (and start (> depth 0))
      (c-put-font-lock-face start (point) 'font-lock-comment-face)))))
nil)

(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '((my-c-mode-font-lock-if0 (0 font-lock-comment-face prepend))) 'add-to-end))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

### I'm not sure if above code can be modified to highlight multiline macro.

[scottmcpeak.com/elisp/scott.emacs.el](http://scottmcpeak.com/elisp/scott.emacs.el)

There is mention of

;'("^([ \t]*#.*(\\\n.*)*)" 1 font-lock-preprocessor-face) 
; this 2nd line is my attempt to get it to recognize multiline macros 
; and highlight them entirely as preprocessor (doesn't work..)

Comment: If you give us a `major-mode` and a sample that we can block and copy over to our own Emacs buffer, it sure would be much easier for us to give you multiple solutions -- even if that type coding is not something we normally do.  Many here are semi-familiar with `font-lock`, and if we can compare what is already available in the `major-mode` source code being used to create the highlighting, we can determine what type of tweaking / adjusting might be needed.  As it stands now, we would need to pull up your image and manually type your example into our Emacs buffer . . . and then guess . . .

Comment: lawlist. I agree. Let me add more info and easy way to get the code also. Reason I put screenshot , so that it easy to compare what i'm looking for.

Comment: `CALL_MACRO` is not coming up in a word search of all `elisp` source code files of Emacs.  Would it be sufficient to just highlight that whenever it is used, or is it really important that it **only** be highlighted **when** sandwiched between `#define . . .` and `#undef . . .` ?

Comment: For example, here is a simple way to highlight just the `CALL_MACRO...` without checking to see whether it is sandwiched between `#define...` and `#undef...`:  `(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda () (my-c-mode-common-hook) (font-lock-add-keywords nil (list (list "\\(CALL_MACRO\\)\\(\(\\)\\([0-9]\\)\\(\)\\)" '(1 font-lock-keyword-face t) '(2 font-lock-string-face t) '(3 font-lock-warning-face t) '(4 font-lock-string-face t))))))`  Of course, you can change the colors to anything you want -- there may also be no reason why the opening and closing parenthesis need to be a separate region.

Comment: lawlist, i just mentioned CALL_MACRO as an example. I've large code base which has so many macros like above. I wanted to highlight those macro definition so that, i can understand if a statement is part of macro or outside macro. Generally, writing such macro in c code is not advised but my code base has those and cant avoid it fully.

Comment: http://scottmcpeak.com/elisp/scott.emacs.el       There is mention of     ;'("^\\([ \t]*#.*\\(\\\\\n.*\\)*\\)" 1 font-lock-preprocessor-face)
      ; this 2nd line is my attempt to get it to recognize multiline macros
      ; and highlight them entirely as preprocessor (doesn't work..)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49618/discussion-between-xprog-and-lawlist)

Comment: With your example in the question above, open up `M-x re-builder` and insert your sample regexp of `^\([ \t]*#.*\(\\\\\n.*\)*\)` -- you'll see that nothing gets highlighted.  It's probably something more like `^\\([ \t]*#.*\\(\\\\\n.*\\)*\\)`; however, that still doesn't highlight what you want.  Go ahead and experiment constructing regexp -- e.g., copy and paste my sample regexp into the quotation marks of re-builder `\\(CALL_MACRO\\)\\(\(\\)\\([0-9]\\)\\(\)\\)`.  I'm really just a novice *wanna-be* programmer and most everyone who reads these threads are light-years ahead of me . . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just came across an awesome package by @Lindydancer called [`prepaint.el`](https://github.com/Lindydancer/prepaint), that does exactly what you want. It highlights macros differently, including multi-line macros and also preserves the keyword highlighting in the macros.

Comment: Great. It works for large amount of code base what i have. I know one issue i would say with above approach in emacs, it doesnt highlight keywords inside multiple macro. However, its not part of this question. I will accept this answer. If you know how to get keywords inside multiple macro to be highlighted along with entire highlight (exact similar to vim), It will be great.

Comment: @Xprog, unfortunately I could not get proper highlighting in the macros. Also highlighting macro using `font-lock` interface was not working well. You can use the above though it is hacky. Maybe someone more experienced with elisp will come up with better solution.

Comment: @Xprog, check my updated answer, I think it answers your question completely.

Comment: @lqbal. nice. thanks for the reference to prepaint.el. I will try today and update here. Currently, my .emacs is outgrown and trying to cleanup.